# Ibn Ezra: Moshe = Monius?

Tags: names, moshe-rabbeinu, etymology, parashas-shemos, avraham-ibn-ezra

Ibn Ezra in his [commentary to Shemos 2:10](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=2&perek=2&mefaresh=ezra) says that the name Moshe was a translation of the Egyptian "Monius". I have, then, two questions:

1) Where does he get that his name was that? And 2) how is that related with something like "drawn from water"?

Related: [Moses' Hebrew name was given to him in Egyptian?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89130/moses-hebrew-name-was-given-to-him-in-egyptian)

Comment: See also https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/2299/228

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79307/what-egyptian-greek-text-was-ibn-ezra-consulting-for-his-commentary-on-the-name?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Immediately after stating that that was Moshe's name he tells us where he got it from:

> ככה כתוב בספר עבודת האדמה הנעתק מלשון מצרים אל לשון קדרים גם ככה בספרי
>   חכמי יוון

That is, he got it from earlier Egyptian and Greek books.

Comment: What we know about this book? Does it answers the second question why he was called that?

Comment: Specifically some sort of agricultural text, which would contain a word like "draw water."

Comment: @RenatoGrun See [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/91695/13438) to the linked question which explains the Egyptian meaning of the word.

Comment: @Shalom, a link to this (a direct reference) would be nice.

Comment: @Alex Your answer there (and others) deals with Moshe = Mose etymology, not Monius, which is a complete different Egyptian word.

Comment: @RenatoGrun Fair point, though it doesn't impact my answer here.

Comment: @Alex, Indeed. But consider adding more information on this book and where it states such etymology (aka Monios = drawn from water).

Comment: @RenatoGrun I don't know anything about the book. All I know is that a translation of a translation of a translation of the title would be something like "Work of the Ground".

Comment: @RenatoGrun In English the book is known as Nabatean Agriculture. The Rambam mentions it as העבודה הנבטית ([MN 3:29](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/more/c10-2.htm)), the Ramban mentions it as העבודה המצרית in Torat YHVH Temima

Comment: @RenatoGrun According to [here](http://www.filaha.org/author_Ibn_wahshiyah.html#PublishedEditionsTranslations), the book has yet to be completely translated into English. According to [here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%93), the book at least mentions that a certain Nabatean was the master of Adam, so it wouldn't be so far-fetched, in my opinion, that other biblical characters were mentioned there.